# DirectShow CSourceStream filter fails to unload properly

Tags: directshow, flash, video-capture

I am writing a DirectShow capture filter using CSource / CSourceStream as a base but when I access the cam in Firefox + Flash, I get a debug assert and the following debug error when closing Firefox.

```
Cam6.ax(tid 1c98)   133506 : 
Cam6.ax(tid 1c98)   133506 :    ID             Object Description
Cam6.ax(tid 1c98)   133506 : 
Cam6.ax(tid 1c98)   133506 :    19 (001AE940)          Camera Stream
Cam6.ax(tid 1c98)   133507 :    18 (001AE940)                 Camera
Cam6.ax(tid 1c98)   133507 :     6 (001AE940)          Camera Stream
Cam6.ax(tid 1c98)   133507 :     5 (001AE940)                 Camera
Cam6.ax(tid 1c98)   133507 : 
Cam6.ax(tid 1c98)   133507 : Total object count     4
```

From what I can tell this is not my fault. I suspect Flash is uncleanly discarding the DirectShow graph on shutdown. I have read and re-read the MSDN documentation and scoured the net for examples but turned up nothing.

Can anyone help clarify this for me or point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

Feeling a little silly about this. After spending a day looking at reference counts and whatnot, it turned out to be a noobie mistake. I compiled strmbasd.lib with the /MDd flag and my code with the /MD flag. The former was targeting the debug runtime libraries, the later the release runtime libraries.

The linker gave a warning which went unheeded and the code ran up until time to release the DLL. Go figure..

Chalk that one up to stupidity I guess. :)

Comment: As a note, I got the same message (but 2 and 1 objects left over), and it was because ffmpeg indeed wasn't cleaning up right (it should now/soon though), and only occurs with Debug builds, release builds don't do the double check...